# MySQL и MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, mysql

Кто нибудь сталкивался с переходом из **MySQL** в **MariaDB**? Какие проблемы могут возникнуть, есть ли серьезные несовместимости?

**UPD:**

Одна из причин отказа от MySQL:

> После приобретения компании Sun
> Microsystems многие разработчики ПО с
> открытым кодом столкнулись c
> проблемами в выпуске обновлений для
> программного обеспечения, которое
> перешло под контроль Oracle. В
> частности речь идет о самой популярной
> СУБД в мире.
>
> Политика Oracle относительно сокрытия
> информации об уязвимостях, ограничение
> доступа разработчиков к большей части
> системы отслеживания ошибок и отказ от
> публикации сгруппированного журнала
> изменений заставили разработчиков
> поставить под вопрос целесообразность
> использования подобного программного
> обеспечения.

Comment: А есть какие-то плюсы перехода с Mysql на в принципе такую же mysql DB?

Comment: причину перехода я добавил в вопрос. А так да, плюсы есть, вот http://blog.mariadb.org/mariadb-5-3-optimizer-benchmark/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не должно возникнуть никаких.

Comment: перевел ) никаких проблем не возникло :)

Answer (score -1):

проблемы огромные. конфликт библиотек для yum. 
библиотек, у которых идентичное содержимое.

соответственно всё библиотеки, обеспечивающие работу perl,php,java и т.д. будут иметь огромные проблемы с установкой на современных дистрибутивах. во всяком случае через yun вы пакеты не установите. только через make&install. :)

конечно можно попробовать выдернуть все библиотеки, которые вообще ссылаются на базу... ну удачи... проще снести систему.